# Union Result of two queries with proper order

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database Table A And Table B -

```
                   Table `A`
    SN   |    Order1    |   Order2   |   Text
 (INT)   |   (TINYINT)  |  (TINYINT) |  (VARCHAR)
   1001  |      1       |      1     |    ABC
   1001  |      1       |      2     |    DEF
   1001  |      1       |      3     |    GHI
   1001  |      2       |      1     |    IOU
   1001  |      3       |      1     |    JKL     <--
   1001  |      3       |      2     |    LMO
   1001  |      3       |      3     |    UTF
   ....
   1021  |      1       |      1     |    ZXC
   1021  |      1       |      2     |    QWE
   1021  |      2       |      1     |    JKL     <--
   1021  |      3       |      1     |    YOU
```

And In Another Table

```
                   Table `B`
    SN   |    Order1    |     rSN    |   rOrder1
   1021  |      2       |     1001   |      3
```

Now when I query for the data of `1021` the result should be like :-

```
         Result Needed

    1    |      1     |    ZXC
    1    |      2     |    QWE
    2    |      1     |    JKL
    2    |      2     |    LMO
    2    |      3     |    UTF
    3    |      1     |    YOU
```

---

Presently I am trying somthing Like this -

```
SELECT `SN`, `Order1`, `Order2`, `Text` FROM `Table A` 
  WHERE `SN`=1012 
UNION  
SELECT `SN`, `Order1`, `Order2`, `Text` FROM `Table A`  
  WHERE `Table A`.`SN` 
  IN (SELECT  `rSN` FROM `Table B` WHERE `SN`=1021) 
  AND `Table A`.`Order1` 
  IN (SELECT  `Order1` FROM `Table B` WHERE `SN`=1021)
```

Which Is giving the Results Like this :-

```
             Result
  SN | Order1 |   Order2   |    Text
 1021|   1    |      1     |    ZXC
 1021|   1    |      2     |    QWE
 1021|   2    |      1     |    JKL
 1021|   3    |      1     |    YOU
 1001|   3    |      1     |    JKL
 1001|   3    |      2     |    LMO
 1001|   3    |      3     |    UTF
```

What should I do to get the `Order1` and `Order2` of the last three rows of the result be same as the referring Row i.e. like `1001  |  2   |   2   | LMO`

Edit ---

Here I am Thinking to get the  `Order1` values of the `1001` to be same as `Order1` of `1012` when query gives the data output.

As The Order Of the `Text` Is important.

The Order2 Text  is related to its corresponding first value in this Group In Order1
And `Table B` Stores reference to the already entered duplicate related Text in the database and defines its position in the corresponding `SN`

Comment: What `ORDER BY` clauses did you try?

Comment: I tried `ORDER BY Order1, Order2` 
But that do not give the desire result as the text `JKL`, `LMO` , `UTF` Should Ordered before `YOU`

Comment: Well the text is in a column you call "Text" not Order1 or Order2. Anyways, what datatype is the column with text?

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I have no idea what you want. Try simplifying you question down to the minimum that is relevant - see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @wondra I have edited The question.
@Bohemian Thanks Your Link helps me.

I finally found out the solution myself to what I was trying to do Using `JOIN`, `Union` and `ORDER BY`

Now am I supposed to  - (Post Answer to my own Question?? or in comment?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You can either post your answer to your own question — that is explicitly approved in the FAQ — or you could decide that the question and answer won't be much benefit to others and delete the question.  Don't use a comment; you can't control the formatting and there's probably too much information to fit into one 600-character comment anyway.  You could, conceivably, edit the answer into the question, but that is inferior to providing an answer; the question won't get the closure of an accepted answer.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand how rows such as `2, 2, LMO` are generated in the answer (and `2, 3, UTF` too).  Once you've worked out how to get the data values correctly, the ordering of the rows is trivial.  Even if you answer your own question, either the answer or a modification to the question should explain more about how the link to the second order works.  For example, why isn't `1, 3, GHI` required as part of the result set.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have Posted the **Solution** that I struggled out, and tried to clarify your doubts. I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself : -

**Solution**

```
SELECT `Order1`, `Order2`, `Text` FROM `Table A` WHERE `SN` = 1012
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT `Table B`.`Order1`,  `Table A`.`Order2`, `Table A`.`Text` 
FROM  `Table A` JOIN  `Table B` 
WHERE  `Table B`.`rSN` =  `Table A`.`SN` 
      AND  `Table B`.`Order1` =  `Table A`.`Order1` 
      AND `Table B`.`SN` = 1021
ORDER BY `Order1`, `Order2`
```

**Explanation**

The First `SELECT` Selects the `Rows` associated with `1021`

In **Second** Part of query, I wanted the `Text` Of the referred `SN` i.e. `1001`'s row's having `Order1` value `3`(See Table B). 
**But as the referring `SN` *i.e. `1021` have its `Order1` value `2`***, WHERE its Text is `JKL` (See Table A, Pointed Row ("<--") with 1021 SN)
So We want All the values of `Order1` of Text associated with `1001 | 3 |` Formatted As `1001 | 2 |` 
For this above problem `JOIN` Works, Joining gives a table like :-

```
SELECT *  FROM  `Table A` JOIN  `Table B` 
WHERE  `Table B`.`rSN` =  `Table A`.`SN` 
  AND  `Table B`.`Order1` =  `Table A`.`Order1` 
  AND `Table B`.`SN` = 1021

            Table `B`                            Table `A`
 SN  | Order1 |  rSN | rOrder1     ||    SN | Order1 | Order2 | Text
1021 |   2    | 1001 |    3        || 1001  |    3   |    1   | JKL 
1021 |   2    | 1001 |    3        || 1001  |    3   |    2   | LMO
1021 |   2    | 1001 |    3        || 1001  |    3   |    3   | UTF
```

And From this result we can Pick up the result set.
Understanding how `2, 2, LMO` comes -> It is here Now we are picking up the `Table B.Order1` From the JOIN result Instead like **earlier** we were Picking up the `Order1` Of the `1001` instead, which then results into ordering which we didn't wanted.

`why isn't 1, 3, GHI required as a part of result` -> As Its Like Related Information,
The Information with same `Order1` show the related words/information to each other and since `1021` Do not have any related information to `1, 3, GHI` Hence It is **not** required in the result part.

And as Now we already getting the `Order1` of the second query same as it should be `2` not `3` We can now easily Order Them by Order clause

I hope this will clarify the question also.
Still Thanks everyone :)

**------ EDIT -------**

`DISTINCT` in UNION will remove the Duplicate Entry of `JKL` From the final results