# Get the count of the duplicate values in a column with the result of a query

Tags: mysql

I want to get the count how many values are repeating in the result in a column in result of a query.

The result set I am getting from a complex query is -

```
svn rvn eng     count(*)
1   1   Boy            1
2   1   Teacher        1
3   1   Chair          1
3   2   Chairwoman      1
3   3   Chairperson     1
4   1   Without         1
4   2   Without fail    1
5   1   Anyone          1
5   2   Anyone else     1
6   1   Permission      1
```

I just want to get the number of duplicate values in `SVN` coloumn in fourth coloumn.

i.e.

```
svn rvn eng     count(*)
1   1   Boy            1
2   1   Teacher        1

3   1   Chair          3
3   2   Chairwoman      3
3   3   Chairperson     3

4   1   Without         2
4   2   Without fail    2

5   1   Anyone          2
5   2   Anyone else     2
6   1   Permission      1
```

Please Help me out on this, Also please tell me what effect this can cause on the efficiency on the query??

**Note - ** I want the count of the values that are picked up in the result set.
there are more entries with `svn` 1,2,4,6 in the table. but count only how many has been selected.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT1**

Here is my current query :-

```
SELECT `svn` , `rvn` ,`eng` , count(*) FROM 
        (SELECT `svn`, `rvn`, `eng`, `hin` 
              FROM `table1` 
              WHERE `SN` = @sn
            UNION DISTINCT
            SELECT `table1_refer`.`sn_svn` AS 'svn',  
                           `table1`.`rvn`, `table1`.`eng` ,  
                          `vocab_rel`.`hin`
            FROM  `table1` 
            JOIN  `table1_refer` 
            WHERE  `table1_refer`.`rSN` =  `table1`.`SN` 
            AND  `table1_refer`.`svn` =  `table1`.`svn` 
            AND `table1_refer`.`SN` = @sn
        ) AS SUBQUERY
        GROUP BY `svn`,`rvn`
        ORDER BY `svn`, `rvn`
```

Comment: so what is your code in your *complex* query?

Comment: @JW if you want to know more about my present query then here is the link where I have asked to make the present query : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449459/union-result-of-two-queries-with-proper-order

Comment: Are you aware that none of those dreaded backticks are actually necessary in your query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mostly take help from phpmyadmin, so Just for its nice formatting I use it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery inside your current complex query to do this like so:

```
SELECT
  svn, 
  rvn,
  eng,
  (SELECT count(t2.svn)
   FROM Tablename t2
   WHERE t2.svn = t1.svn
  ) AS Count
FROM Tablename t1
....
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2542c/1)

This will give you:

```
| SVN | RVN |         ENG | COUNT |
-----------------------------------
|   1 |   1 |         Boy |     1 |
|   2 |   1 |     Teacher |     1 |
|   3 |   1 |       Chair |     3 |
|   3 |   2 |  Chairwoman |     3 |
|   3 |   3 | Chairperson |     3 |
|   4 |   1 |     Without |     2 |
|   4 |   2 | Withoutfail |     2 |
|   5 |   1 |      Anyone |     2 |
|   5 |   2 |  Anyoneelse |     2 |
|   6 |   1 |  Permission |     1 |
```

Comment: hey thanks, I was wondering how will it affect the efficiency ?? If you can provide some light on this.

Comment: @Sanuj I think this is the only possible way to do so this way. I mean selecting all the rows from the table with a count of duplicates of only one of them. In this case you can't use a `GROUP BY` like what you did. So it will has a poor performance due to this correlated sql query for each row.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal  How can we use the above scenario to join from two or more tables?