# Get number of duplicate rows resulting from a DISTINCT query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with rows where `a`, `b`, and `c` are commonly the same. 
I have a query that gives me each unique record. I'm trying to get the count, of the duplicate records for each distinct record returned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a,
     b,
     c,
     COUNT(id) as counted
FROM 
     table
```

The `COUNT` here returns the count for all the records. What I was looking for was the count of records identical to the unique record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT a,b,c,COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY a,b,c
```

Comment: This also worked. Identical results as far as I can tell, and simpler query.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a,
     b,
     c,
     (
          SELECT 
              COUNT(id) 
          FROM 
              table_name t1
          WHERE 
              t2.a = t1.a
     ) AS counted
FROM 
     table_name t2
```

The above sub query know as inline sub query. in where clause t1 and t2 treat as different table(It's single table in DB) by query. So it check the equality and then count. as we put distinct for a column so all play done with that only.
I hope am able to enplane.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, figured this one out from a duplicate as I was writing the question - I figured I'd share my results as they were different enough from the answer I got mine from.

I have to use a subquery to get query non-distinct records. Then, I can use results from the first query in the subquery's WHERE clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a,
     b,
     c,
     (
          SELECT 
              COUNT(id) 
          FROM 
              table_name t1
          WHERE 
              t2.a = t1.a
     ) AS counted
FROM 
     table_name t2
```

This works. Let me know if there are gaps in my understanding.

With help from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110336/1270996